# Modify Array in swift using if var =

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

starting swift this past days i'm facing something that looks so simple but this makes me blow my mind.

I have an array myArray which is of type [[String:Any]].

I want simply want to modify an array by adding stuff in it :

```
    if var tempValue = self.myArray[0]["values"] as? [AnyObject] {
        tempValue.append("hello")
        // if i print content of self.myArray it is empty
        self.matches[0]["values"] = ["hello", "hello2"]
        // this lines does work
    }
```

i do not understand why when i mutate tempValue the referenced array is not mutated ? Is this a new value ?

Thanks for any explanations.

Comment: `[String:Any]` this is not an array but dictionary

Comment: *"the referenced array ..."* – your problem starts here. Arrays are *value types*.

Comment: Yep sorry Ozgur. i edited that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `[String:Any]` is not array, it is `Dictionary<String, Any>`. I think you mean that `myArray` have type `[[String:Any]]`

2) `Array` and `Dictionary` types passes by value in swift, not by reference. So `tempValue` is different instance with same values

You can try this code:

```
(self.myArray[0]["values"] as? [AnyObject])?.append("hello") // - wrong!!
```

**UPDATE:**

Thought this answer marked as correct, I found issue in it. Seems like result of `(self.myArray[0]["values"] as! [AnyObject])` (even with force unwrapping) will be immutable array. So you can not use `append` method in it. You need overwrite whole key with new array:

```
if var tempValue = self.myArray[0]["values"] as? [AnyObject] {
    tempValue.append("hello")
    self.myArray[0]["values"] = tempValue
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

About passing data between view controllers. Let me show you one of my solutions for modify settings of `firstViewController` from `secondViewController`. First I define settings class:

```
class ControllerSettings: NSObject {
    var userInfo = Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>()
    var myArray = [AnyObject]()
    override var description: String {return "- userInfo: \(userInfo)\n - myArray: \(myArray)"}
}
```

`firstViewController` will use `settings` property for save it settings, and pass reference to this property to child `secondViewController`; after `secondViewController` will modify it and dismiss, `firstViewController` will able to check changes in `viewWillAppear` method

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var settings = ControllerSettings()
    //...

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
        print("here is actual settings:\n\(settings)")
        //...
    }
    //...

    func showSecondController() {
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.firstViewControllerSettings = settings
        presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var firstViewControllerSettings: ControllerSettings?
    //...

    func mutateSettingsAndDismiss() {
        firstViewControllerSettings?.myArray.append("NewSetting")
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. So i need to use NSMutableArray to be able to use references ? If i want to pass data between UIViewControllers and that i want to change data from one controller that will update the other. How can i do that ? Thank you man.

Comment: @user2434385 I found issue in answer, please check correction. If you have complex data with nested mutated arrays/dictionaries, then I suggest you to write custom class for this needs.

Comment: thank u man, do u know any tutorial or example for this kind of custom class ?

Comment: i do not understand why even with force unwrapping the compiler tells me it's a immutable array ...

Comment: @user2434385 check my suggest (update 2) for passing data between view controllers, maybe it will help you.